# Problem in setting list reference

Tags: cross-referencing, listings

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Some Java code},label={lst:label},language=Java]
// Code...
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={ Java code},label={lst:n7},language=Java]
// Code...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

When run the code, list references properly appear like list 1 and list 2.

When copy same code in another project and want to ref the list 1. Then instead of list 1 it appears as list?? Not automatically picking the reference number(although same data is being copied).

Comment: Sorry, don‘t get your point. Can you please add the two modifications to your code, i.e. the reference from some text AND the copy plus reference from text? Thank you

Comment: Latex needs two runs to resolve references. What happens. When you compile again?